# Android Studio - Android Gradle plugin 1.3.0 is not supported

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I recently updated Android Studio to Version 1.3.2. After upgrading Android SDK Tools to v24.3.4 and Platform-tools to v23, when compiling my project, I get the following message:

```
Error:Gradle 2.4 requires Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 (or newer)  but project      
is using version 1.1.0.
Please use Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 or newer.
```

My previous build.gradle file looked like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0-rc3'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'



repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

Moving on and changing the classpath of the "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0-rc3" to **"com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0"** and get the following message:

```
Error:The Android Gradle plugin 1.3.0 is not supported.
```

My gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file looks like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

I tried many different combinations, but fail to get it to work, I always get the "plugin xxxx is not supported" error message. What am I missing here? Any hint would be appreciated.

Some useful links regarding the plugin:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle
https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: Right click on your application and go to Open Module Settings. Then go to Project and change the Android Plugin Version from 1.1.0 to whatever you need?

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. I figured out that the Robolectric plugin was causing the error. The solution was rather simple: removing the Robolectric plugin from gradle and upgrading my testCompile include to 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'. Robolectric plugin is deprecated since version 3.0. See https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin